# C Memory allocation, overwriting after freeing

Tags: c, pointers, memory, free

I am stuck on a question about memory allocation, particularly what happens after the free() statements. So for example, when I free a and then change its address, will a still have its old value or will it get the address of the b? Does a become a dangling pointer because I adjust it after I free it? Is the output simply going to be a and b with the same values, z-20 and w=9? 
I'd appreciate any help. Thank you very much!

```
int* t = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)); 
int* b = (int*)    malloc(sizeof(int)); 
int* a = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)); 
int w;
int z;

*a = 11;
*b = 9;
z = *a + *b; 
w = *b;
*a = z; 
free(a);

*t = 4;
b = &z;
a = b; 
free(t);

printf("Printed results are:\n");
printf("*a=%d, *b=%d, z=%d, w=%d\n", *a, *b, z, w);
```

Comment: You can't change the address of a variable.

Comment: Thou shalt not cast the result of `malloc()`!

Comment: `b = &z;` memory initially allocated for b no longer accessable and leaking.

Comment: Why can't you compile it and find the result for yourself?

Comment: "overwriting after freeing" - you're freeing the block of memory that a was pointing to. At that point, the pointer value that a has is invalid i.e. you should no longer use *a. (In practice you'd probably get away with it, but don't.) It's safe to reuse the pointer variable a to point to something else though, as you're doing here. In that case it will now point to a different value, yes: the value that was in the malloced memory at a at the point it was freed will (in theory) be lost.

Comment: As a follow-on to the comment by @Swordfish, See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) Just a note, the `'*'` generally is attached to the variable instead of the type. `int* a, b, c;` most certainly does not declare three pointers to `int`. Rather `int *a, b, c;` makes that much more apparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I free a and then change its address, will a still have its old value or will it get the address of the b

It will get the pointer value in b, which is the address of z.

The code should free b before reassigning it to the address of z:

```
free(b);
b = &z;
```

otherwise I don't see a problem with the code, as it doesn't appear to be dereferencing any freed pointers.

> output

It is what you would expect:

```
*a=20, *b=20, z=20, w=9
```